# How to add Icons from "conditional formatting>Icon sets" to individual cells?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I'm trying to add to individual cells the icons from "Conditional Formatting -> Icon sets" in Excel (the traffic lights, or the rhomboid shapes, etc.) to individual cells.

I've only found this in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.iconset
But I cannot find any example code where a condition is not necessary.

Let's say I would like to add the yellow circle to cell "A1", how could I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible without a condition because the icons are from conditional formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let's say I would like to add the yellow circle to cell "A1", how could I do this?

As @Pᴇʜ mentioned that these icons are from icon sets and cannot be used without conditional formatting. Having said that we can fake the traffic lights.

**Logic**

1. There is a symbol which you can use from the **Insert | Symbol** menu. It looks like as shown below

   [image]
2. Simply insert the symbol at the begining of the cell text and change the font to **Wingdings** and **Forecolor** to relevant color. Feel free to set the font size as well.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Const TrafficLightSignal As String = "l"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    InsertTrafficLightSignal ws.Range("A1"), -16727809 '<~~ Orange
    InsertTrafficLightSignal ws.Range("A2"), -11489280 '<~~ Green
    InsertTrafficLightSignal ws.Range("A3"), -16776961 '<~~ Red
End Sub

Private Sub InsertTrafficLightSignal(rng As Range, SignalColor As Long)
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    For Each aCell In rng
        With aCell
            '~~> You can add a space between them as well if you want
            '.Value = TrafficLightSignal & " " & aCell
            .Value = TrafficLightSignal & aCell

            With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font
                .Name = "Wingdings"
                .FontStyle = "Regular"
                .Size = 17 '<~~ Change Font size as applicable
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .OutlineFont = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                .Color = SignalColor '<~~ Color is changed here
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
            End With
        End With
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

**Alternative icons**

You can also chose this icon if you want

[image]

For this, in the above code use these instead

```
Const TrafficLightSignal As String = "n"
```

and

```
.Name = "Webdings" 'instead of Wingdings
```

**Output**:

[image]

Whatever symbol you choose ensure it is black (i.e filled up) so that the font color can be changed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I can use this. Also I really appreciate the code attached, will definitely use it!

Comment: While it doesn't give the exact same symbols, and the font formatting (sizing) is slightly off in comparison to the icon sets, this solution is super helpful!